# How to replace a standard 2-gang light switch with an electric dimmer switch

Tags: electrical, lighting, light-fixture, home-automation

I'm looking for a some assistance in fitting a new electric dimmer light switch. I'm in the UK if that makes a difference.

I am trying to replace my existing two-gang light switch with a LightWaveRF two gang dimmer but am not sure where to start as the instructions are telling me to look out for colored cables that aren't present in the existing switch.

Here's my **original light switch setup**:

[image: The back of the switch]

Here's the **new LightWaveRF switch**:

[image: The back of the dimmer]

What steps to I need to follow to install this switch?

Here's what's in the wall (just in case we need to use these!)

[image: The rest of the wiring]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have included two images. The first identifies the wires in your current switch and the second image identifies where to put said wires.

In case your wondering the "S" terminals are for slave units

[image: Annotated switch image]

[image: Annotated dimmer image]